# Cannot hide UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

For my app, I've attempted to make a UIDatePicker appear when the textfield called time is clicked.

In my viewDidLoad, I initialize it like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

time.delegate = self;
[time setValue:[UIColor darkGrayColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];

datepicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
datepicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer;
dateformatter= [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

}
```

Then, in the textFieldShouldBeginEditing method, I have this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

if (textField == time){
    button.hidden = NO;
    datepicker.hidden = NO;

}

    return NO;
}
```

However, my UIDatePicker still stays hidden, and I am sure the outlets are connected

Comment: Where do you add the picker as a subview in your view ?

Comment: picker placed in .xib?

Comment: If he initializes his date picker the IBOutlet is irrelevant

Comment: no need to put Picker in .xib file, look at my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove this line from your code and check ,if your picker is placed in Xib.

```
datepicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

In textFieldShouldBeginEditing you need to set frame according to your need and than you have to add date picker to your view. for example

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    if (textField == _time){

        CGRect frame = datepicker.frame;
        frame.origin.x = 100(for eg,set according to you);
        frame.origin.y = 100(for eg,set according to you);
        datepicker.frame = frame;
        [self.view addSubview:datepicker];
        button.hidden = NO;
        datepicker.hidden = NO;

    }

    return NO;
}
```

remove after you done with this.